# Make a table TR use full width and other normal columns

Tags: html, css

I'm working in a project, where I am making a table, which looks something like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> <!-- this should be full width -->
      <td colspan="3"><span> Very long long text</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col content 1</td>
      <td>Col content 2</td>
      <td>Col content 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the first `tr`, to be a full width element.
What is happening now is that the `td[colspan="3"]` uses 1 column, so the first column of the last tr, is larger.

### EDIT

[image]

Here is a basic example, first column is very long, much that it's content, making every thing go off screen

Comment: I don't see any issue... could you please explain?

Comment: If I'm understanding, what you have should work as desired - the first row should be a single cell spanning the full width, and the second row should have three cells each 1/3 the width. You could try adding `td { border:1px solid black; }` so you can see the outlines of the table cells.

Comment: Agreed - unclear what you are trying to do - https://jsfiddle.net/5tajre2u/

Comment: Checkout screenshot added. Helps?

Comment: Nope....less clear now. Please reproduce in a [mcve]

Comment: You could try using `table {table-layout:fixed; width:100%;}`

Comment: Looking at the image, it seems like the "Long Text" cell is indeed expanding past the first cell of the following row as desired. Are you sure there is no content *below* the two (three if you count the header) rows displayed that is forcing the first column to be wider? Without explicit widths there is a lot of calculation in the rendering engine to allocate the available space.

Comment: **html and screenshot you provided obviously do not match**. Make an example that shows your issue. (within a snippet here, a http://jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io/pen ) in order to get efficient help. **Your code works fine:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zowvKR .**

Answer (score -2):

you are using html, so to change the css, you need to say : 
`style="colspan:3;"`
that should work

Comment: colspan is not a style

Answer (score -2):

there is no issue with your tags you better clear the cache of your browser 
sometimes it happens on chrome press CTRL+F5 to clear the cache or use another browser like Firefox if you are using the Firefox press CTRL+F5.